# Excel vLookup from Outlook - Best Practices

Tags: excel, outlook

I'm trying to build some automation into Outlook, I receive a series of emails throughout the day; around 75. In each of these emails there is a particular string that I need to lookup on an Excel sheet and forward the email based on the retrieved results. I've researched several methods and they all seem clunky or problematic to me, I was hoping to get feedback on best practices to accomplish this.

So far, I've investigated :

- Opening a background Excel doc hosted on a network drive, perform the vlookup and close the document. However, the network can sometimes bog down the opening of the file and having Outlook intermittently freeze is unacceptable.
- Opening a background Excel doc hosted on a network drive and leave the file open in the background; to be used when needed. My issue is that I'm having a hard time keep the reference to the document as Outlook likes to "forget" it was there.
- Converting the file to an Access Database (I have very limited experience here) hoping that Access has better tools for quickly querying files.

Again, I'm looking for advice on best practices.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can copy the Excel file to your computer every day and then do the lookups on that.